# How get tag attribute by javascript without using id or class?

Tags: javascript

I am new in javascript.I am trying this below code to get href attribute.

```
<a href="facebook.com"  onclick="cheak()">Facebook</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        function cheak()
        {
            var a= document.getElementsByTagName("a").getAttribute('href');
            alert(a);
        }

</script>
```

I know this is working by below code

```
document.getElementById("myid").getAttribute('href');  // if I use any id
```

But in tag I don't want to use any id or class. How can I get this attribute without using any id or class in `a` tag.

Comment: Are you *only* trying to get the element from within the `cheak` function? If so, [Zain's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32134008/157247) is the correct one.

Comment: Side note: That `href` is incorrect. It should be `href="http://facebook.com"` or `href="https://facebook.com"`. Just `href="facebook.com"` is a *relative* URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface:** Below, I've answered the question of how to find an element without using an `id` or `class`, in the general case. But if you just want the element from within your `cheak` function, then [Zain's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32134008/157247) is the correct way to do that (with minimal changes to your code; arguably *more* correct might be modern event hookup).

---

> But in tag I don't want to use any id or class. How can I get this attribute without using any `id` or `class` in `a` tag.

You reach for the Swiss army knife of element selection: `document.querySelector`. With it, you can use any [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) that matches the element:

```
var href = document.querySelector("any selector here").getAttribute("href");
```

`querySelector` returns the **first** match in the document. (There's also `querySelectorAll`, which returns a list.) They're both supported in all modern browsers, and also IE8.

Since you have the full power of CSS selectors, you can use anything about the position of the element in the document to find it.

There's too little context in your question for a specific example, but for instance if it's the **first** `a` in the document:

```js
var href = document.querySelector("a").getAttribute("href");
alert(href);
```

```html
<a href="facebook.com"  onclick="cheak()">Facebook</a>
```

Or using that `onclick`:

```js
var href = document.querySelector("a[onclick='cheak()']").getAttribute("href");
alert(href);
```

```html
<a href="facebook.com"  onclick="cheak()">Facebook</a>
```

Comment: I read in a tutorial that the methods `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are less performant than using `getElementsByTagName` for such kind of manipulations. Any experience about that?

Comment: @JoëlSalamin: They're different tools for different jobs. I think when you use `querySelectorAll` with just a tag name (e.g., for what `getElementsByTagName` does), yes, it's slower, because it has to A) Parse the selector, and then B) Build a disconnected collection; in contrast, `getElementsByTagName` returns the live collection the browser probably already has. But of course, you can't do my second example above with `getElementsByTagName` (you'd need a loop in your code; likely slower). And 99.9% of the time, it doesn't matter; the vast majority of code is not performance-critical. :-)

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer, you're right the tutorial was only comparing `getElementsByTagName` and `querySelectorAll` for manipulations on a simple collection of elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you pass in `this` when calling the function. it will pass the element reference to your function and you can use it to get value of href:

```
<a href="facebook.com"  onclick="cheak(this)">Facebook</a>
<!-- Note -----------------------------^^^^            -->

<script type="text/javascript">
function cheak(a) {
     alert(a.href); // Gives you the fully-resolved URL
     alert(a.getAttribute("href")); // Gives you the content of the `href` attribute (not fully-resolved)
}
</script>
```

the parameter `data` is the complete tag on which the function is called

Comment: It has nothing to do with the initial question but I have a remark on the solution you're proposing. If you simply keep calling the method `cheak` without any parameter, the `this` keyword will automatically reference the calling element inside the method, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: `this` is sent when you are using jQuery. but in native Js you need to send it manually.

Comment: @ZainAftab: No, that's incorrect. If you use modern element hookup (`addEventListener`; `attachEvent` on old IE), `this` will refer to the element the event was hooked on. It's just `onXyz` attributes where you have to pass it in as you are above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Now I understand why I worked well without passing any parameter and using `this` keyword: it wasn't with a legacy `onxxx` method. Thanks for this clarification!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="www.facebook.com"  onclick="cheak(event)">Facebook</a>

     <script type="text/javascript">
    function cheak(e)
    {
       e.preventDefault(); 
      //  var a= document.getElementsByTagName("a").getAttribute('href');
        alert(e.target);
    }

</script>
```